# Best way to make a file writeable in c#

Tags: c#, .net, file, file-attributes

I'm trying to set flag that causes the `Read Only` check box to appear when you `right click \ Properties` on a file.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to make the file read only, per your question, or writeable (not read only), per your question title?

Comment: This is a complicated issue on Win2k based OSes.  There's the read-only attribute you can give a file, and there's also Write-permission which is granted via the "Permissions" tab.  The former is just a suggestion, where as the latter is actually enforced by the operating system.

Comment: @Armentage I don't think it's that complicated. There's a clear distinction between file flags and NTFS permission sets, and this question clearly deals with the first case.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Two ways:

```
System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(filePath);
fileInfo.IsReadOnly = true/false;
```

or

```
// Careful! This will clear other file flags e.g. `FileAttributes.Hidden`
File.SetAttributes(filePath, FileAttributes.ReadOnly/FileAttributes.Normal);
```

The `IsReadOnly` property on `FileInfo` essentially does the bit-flipping you would have to do manually in the second method.

Comment: Amazing how fast you can get an answer around here. I love this site!

Comment: I didn't realize you could use the first method.  Awesome!

Comment: Note that this will effectively clear out the other flags on the same file at the same time. A hidden file will become visible, a system-file will become non-system, etc.

Comment: @Lasse the second method will, if someone does not understand how bit flags work. Thankfully you explained it already.

Comment: The first method shortens to `new FileInfo(filePath) { IsReadOnly = false };`, which is neat!

Answer (score 37):

To **set** the read-only flag, in effect making the file non-writeable:

```
File.SetAttributes(filePath,
    File.GetAttributes(filePath) | FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
```

To **remove** the read-only flag, in effect making the file writeable:

```
File.SetAttributes(filePath,
    File.GetAttributes(filePath) & ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
```

To **toggle** the read-only flag, making it the opposite of whatever it is right now:

```
File.SetAttributes(filePath,
    File.GetAttributes(filePath) ^ FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
```

This is basically bitmasks in effect. You set a specific bit to set the read-only flag, you clear it to remove the flag.

Note that the above code will not change any other properties of the file. In other words, if the file was hidden before you executed the above code, it will stay hidden afterwards as well. If you simply set the file attributes to `.Normal` or `.ReadOnly` you might end up losing other flags in the process.

Comment: imho this is the best method.

Answer (score 1):

C# :

```
File.SetAttributes(filePath, FileAttributes.Normal);

File.SetAttributes(filePath, FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
```

Answer (score 0):

One-line answer (without changing other file attributes):

```
new FileInfo(filename).IsReadOnly = true/false;
```