# TFS Build Workflow Change Folder/File Attributes From Read-Only to Read/Write?

Tags: .net, tfs, workflow, tfsbuild

In one of our web applications, it is required that some HTML pages be editable in a GUI interface we created for the user.  Unfortunately, the interface directly reads/writes from a page on the server (also in the wwwroot).  Another page on the server reads from it and just displays it.

What I have now done is changed our entire build process so that nothing is manual anymore and I am now using the build workflow with TFS/VS 2010 which is nice.

But TFS automatically puts everything in read-only mode when it deploys the code.

**Is there a way to programatically (at any step in the process), change the attributes of a folder/file from read-only to read-write so that the web interface still works correctly?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about adding a custom code activity that runs post-deploy to update the [attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileattributes.aspx) of the files to not FileAttributes.Normal? This activity should probably run on the controller at the end of the build.

You might want to check out Ewald Hofman's [series](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/29/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-4-Create-your-own-activity.aspx) of build customization. Your build service account will likely have the correct permissions to update the deployed file attributes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is exactly what we also did at some point in the past. We had gotten help into writing the actual activity from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202022/best-way-to-make-a-file-writeable-in-c)

Comment: A custom activity is not needed. It is sufficient to have an "InvokeProcess" activity in your build template executing the "attrib" command with "-r /s *", for instance.

Answer (score 1):

I bumped on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6765991/remove-read-only-attribute-on-folder-on-a-network-share) & assume it's connected with this question as well.

What @Duat suggests has worked for me, within the scope of the Build-Agent server. Yet, in your other question, you mention a net-drive - so I suppose you 're talking about file(s) residing either in the drop location of your build, or on the target computer where MSBuild/MSDeploy deploys your solution.

I will advance with the first assumption (so, we 'll focus on Drop Location), but it should be similar to handle the matter in either case.
The idea bases on a strategically placed 'xcopy'. ('xcopy' per default resets all file attributes into read-write during execution)
 The first step is to construct a custom activity that sets the files you need into read-write. A quick first draft of the activity can be this (it's meant to change the attributes of a file, not a dir):

```
namespace BuildTasks.Activities
{
    using System;
    using System.Activities;
    using System.IO;
    using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client;

    [BuildActivity(HostEnvironmentOption.Agent)]
    public sealed class MakeFileWriteable : CodeActivity
    {
        [RequiredArgument]
        public InArgument<string> FilePath
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
        {
            String filePath = FilePath.Get(context);

            //add exception handling 

            FileAttributes fileAttributes = File.GetAttributes(filePath);
            File.SetAttributes(filePath, fileAttributes & ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
        }
    }
}
```

The second step, now once you have `MakeFileWritable` in your build solution, is to change your build definition from this
[image]

into something like this
[image]

The file in `MakeFileWriteable` should be from within the BuildAgent and is the FROMFILE in the InvokeProcess that follows:
[image]

TOFILE is where the file should land.
Remember to set the "/Y" in the arguments, since you 'll be overwriting the file.